# Encoding issues from python 2.7.x to 3.5.x

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I am currently porting some python 2.7.x code to python 3.5.x.

One of the scripts I ported using 2to3 failed. It is a simple script that reads home-brewd config files. The thing is, those files contain commentaries in French, with accents so they are encoded in latin_1 (iso-8859-1). Previously in Python 2.7.x, the script did something like this:

```
with open(path_to_file, 'r') as myfile:
    out_lines = myfile.readlines()
```

Then:

```
for i, line in enumerate(out_lines):
    line = line.strip()
    ... some checks on what line contains
```

Eventually, if line is not a commentary or an include of another config file, then it eventually does a `print(line)`. That script is called from a program in C, which then catches the output of the python `print` and interprets its content. In python 2.7.x, it works without specifying what the encoding is.

---

Now in python 3.5.x, the call to `open` fails with the following exception:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe9 in position 370: ordinal not in range(128)
```

I tried several things:

- Running `open` with `'rb'` to read bytes and not interpret them. However the `print` then returns lines starting with `b'` and ending with `\n'`, which the C program cannot understand.
- Running `open` with `encoding="latin_1"`. File gets read, but `print` fails again. To get print to run, I overrode the encoding of stdout (which was set to ANSI_X3.4-1968) to utf-8 using `sys.stdout = codecs.getwriter("latin_1")(sys.stdout.detach())`. That felt quite "dirty" so in the end I exported `PYTHONIOENCODING="utf-8"` and it worked.

My question is: why did it use to work in Python 2.7.x ? How come that with an ascii input/output, the line containing accents and special characters could be read and then printed ? This probably has something to do with strings in python 3 being unicode, but I'm at a loss here. Also if you think that my "fix" is not the right one, feel free to give some advice in comments/answers.

Comment: Python 3 change of string handling to more sensible method. In fact, what we did in python 2 are indeed some hack. http://pythoncentral.io/encoding-and-decoding-strings-in-python-3-x/  . Thus, cause the  "forward incompatible"

Comment: You have separate issues. You should not rely on the default encoding when opening a file (do use `encoding='...'` with a fitting codec when opening a file) *and* you have printing issues; `ANSI_X3.4-1968` is the ASCII codec, it means your stdout locale is set to `C`.

Comment: Python 2 ignored encodings in text. You basically passed through binary data, with a little bit of line ending translation thrown in.